# Generating timed `click` events automatically, using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I created three buttons and created three different jQuery `click` functions for the same to display some text in a `div`.

How to generate `click` events (timed) automatically when the user fails to click the button in the first 10 seconds?

**Details:** I am using (jQuery 1.11.0 + HTML5 + CSS3)

Comment: Try to use settimeout: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Answer (score 2):

Use plain JavaScript function [setTimeout()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) on initialization (call the click handler after 10 seconds) and clear the timeout if one of the buttons has been clicked (i.e. from your click handler)

Answer (score 2):

## Example One: Iterate through each button

### [Live demo of button iteration](http://jsfiddle.net/6b5g2/)

This will click (starting at the end) each button after XXXX number of milliseconds.  In the fiddle I use 1000 ms so you don't have to wait 10 seconds to see a result.

```
var num = document.getElementsByClassName('clicker').length,
    iterate = setInterval(function () {
        $('input[type="button"]').eq(num).click();
        num--;
        if (num < 0) clearInterval(iterate);
    }, 10000);
$('input').click(function () {
    alert('clicked number ' + this.id);
});
```

## Example Two: Already know which button to go for

### [Live demo for individual button](http://jsfiddle.net/PjL22/)

Just replace `#one` with the button selector and you're good to go.  If you click it before the timeout completes, the timeout is cancelled.

```
var autoClick = setTimeout(function () {
    $('#one').click();
}, 10000);
$('#one').on('click', function () {
    clearTimeout(autoClick);
    // Do something for this button
});
```